# How to set via jQuery a value into an input field, created by a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

When having a list of html input boxes, made from an array, which might look like this

```js
    $('#option_dyn[0][name]').val();
$('#option_dyn[0][name]').val("foo");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="option_dyn[0][name]" name="option_dyn[0][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="name0here">
<input id="option_dyn[1][name]" name="option_dyn[1][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="name1here">
<input id="option_dyn[2][name]" name="option_dyn[2][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="name2here">
```

I expect using

```
$('#option_dyn[0][name]').val();
```

should return the given value, and

```
$('#option_dyn[0][name]').val("foo");
```

should set the value to "foo", but it's not.
Please give me a hint how to set these input boxes.

Comment: I would highly advise against using brackets `[]` inside ids, because they're reserved as seperate selector for key=values such as: `$('[type="text"]')` 
or `$('input[name="option_dyn[0][name]"]')`

Comment: You can use the backslash to escape them though for the selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//escape the brackets
console.log($('#option_dyn\\[0\\]\\[name\\]').val());
//or use the native method
console.log($(document.getElementById('option_dyn[0][name]')).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="option_dyn[0][name]" name="option_dyn[0][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="name0here">
```

Comment: This one helped a lot in my special case! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add the index of the current item to the id for each generated input. As the first comment says avoid using [] inside id's....

```
var idPrefix = "option_dyn";

        var myArray = [
            {
                "key": "somevalueA"
            },
            {
                "key": "somevalueB"
            },
            {
                "key": "somevalueC"
            },
            {
                "key": "somevalueD"
            }
        ];

        var container = $("<div>", { "class": "your-class" });

        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            var inputElement = $("<input>", { "id": `option_dyn${i}`, "type": "text", "value": myArray[i].key });
            container.append(inputElement);
        }

        $('body').append(container);

        var testId = `#${idPrefix}` + '0'; 
        $(testId).val('Some Value');

        console.log($(testId).val());
```

[image]